# I want to delete all products from a table(products) where a product is only represented in one category

Tags: sql

Like the title says, i would like to delete all products in categoryID 102, but not if they are ALSO represented in any other categoryid.

Pseudo: Delete x where categoryid = 102, and x is not in any other category.

I gotta select from 3 tables: Product, Category, Product_Category_Mapping

This is what i have now:

```
select p.Name 
from Product p, Category c, Product_Category_Mapping pcm 
where c.Id = 102 and pcm.CategoryId = c.Id and pcm.ProductId = p.Id
```

I bet this is pretty simple. I might need a subselect?

Comment: Can you please provide the `table structure` along with the some `data` and the `expected outcome` ?

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a set-within-a-sets query.  A good way to handle this is with `group by` and `having`.  Here is an example for two products:

```
select p.Name 
from Product_Category_Mapping pcm join
     Product p
     on pcm.ProductId = p.Id
where pcm.id in (102, 103)
group by p.Name
having count(distinct pcm.id) = 2;
```

Comment: This solves for 102 and 103, but what about items other than 103, or 102, 103 and 104?

Comment: @AdriaanStander I need exactly this. Everything else than 102, but also 102.

Comment: If you want for all `id`, remove the `where` clause. It will give you result with all `ids` including `102`.

Comment: So if i remove "where pcm.id in (102,103)" and change having count(distinct pcm.id) from 2 to 1 i end up with all products which is only in category 102? Thats what i need. I actually want to delete all products that are ONLY in 102.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff i added some new text to my question. I want to delete all products which is in categoryid 102, but if they are in any other category i dont want to delete them.

Comment: If you don't want the products which are in `102`, replace `where` clause with `where pcm.id not in (102)`.

Comment: The other way around. I only want products that are in 102, and not in any other category

Comment: Than replace `not in` in where with `in`.

Comment: See my edit. Is that correct? This is for a webshop, so i gotta be absoluty sure i wont delete any products which is in any other category than 102.

No, that is not correct, sorry. I removed 102 from the select. Gotta change it.

Comment: As per your edit, it will give you result for all the `ids`, including `102`. I am not able to understand what do you want. For the two functionality you said, `select / delete`, you will need two different queries. You cannot achieve that with single query.

Comment: Okey, i edited too soon. The latest edit(only delete) is the correct one.

Comment: For not displaying the results for `id = 102` use `"where pcm.id not in (102)" (if you have multiple ids, just include them in the ())` or `"where pcm.id <> 102" (if you have just single id)`

Comment: Still gotta be the other way around. I want to delete all products in category 102, if said product does not exist in any other category.

Comment: Clear me one thing, you want to `delete` the data from the `table` which have category `102` or you just want to `select` all the data from the `table` except the data having category `102` ?

Comment: I want to delete all products in category 102, if they don't exist in any other category. The select i had first was to simplify things, which didn't simplify anything. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify which DBMS you're using, but this is pretty plain vanilla SQL:

```
SELECT p.Id AS ProductId, p.Name AS ProductName
  FROM Product p INNER JOIN Product_Category_Mapping pcm
    ON p.Id = pcm.ProductId
 WHERE pcm.CategoryId = 102
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Product_Category_Mapping pcm2
                     WHERE pcm.ProductId = p.Id
                       AND pcm2.CategoryId <> pcm.CategoryId )
```

Incidentally, joining to `Category` is unnecessary since the `CategoryId` is already present in the `Product_Category_Mapping` table. To delete, just use the above query with an `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM Product
 WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT p.Id AS ProductId
      FROM Product p INNER JOIN Product_Category_Mapping pcm
        ON p.Id = pcm.ProductId
     WHERE pcm.CategoryId = 102
       AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Product_Category_Mapping pcm2
                         WHERE pcm.ProductId = p.Id
                           AND pcm2.CategoryId <> pcm.CategoryId )
)
```

or you might do the following instead:

```
DELETE FROM Product p
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Product_Category_Mapping pcm
                 WHERE pcm.ProductId = p.Id
                   AND pcm.CategoryId = 102 )
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Product_Category_Mapping pcm2
                     WHERE pcm2.ProductId = p.Id
                       AND pcm2.CategoryId <> 102 )
```

Comment: The last query does not work with Product p when using delete, but after testing it with select instead i can see that its selecting what i would like it to. Delete from Product p does not compute however.